# Convert a For loop to While loop in python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert these two **for** loops to **while** loops:

```
sum = 0
for i in range (10, 30):
    for j in range(i, 10*i):
        sum += j
```

Any ideas?

Comment: and why would you want to do that? `for` loops are better

Comment: Where is your coding attempt?  What problems did you encounter?  Why didn't the other for / while conversion Q&A hits solve your problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, you should try to solve the problem yourself and then post your efforts and errors along the way. Also, this code looks like it is best in a for loop, a while loop would be much messier.

Answer (score 1):

What `for i in range(a,b)` does is it runs the loop for value of `i` starting from `a` till it reaches `b-1` , same you can replecate with while loop statement. What we are doing here is **before starting the loop we initiated `i` to be qual to a** and then keep on increasing the value by order of 1 after each iteration.

And before starting next iteration if it's less that `b` if not we don't start the next iteration.

Watch this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3T1yyGQd6o) for more info.

```
sum = 0
i = 10
while i <30:
    j=i
    while j < (10*i):
        sum += j
        j+=1
    i+=1
```

Comment: Probably because "While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so."

Comment: Added explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It is the first time I use this forum. I am new in python and I just wanted to know some more. I really appreciate you help!